# Opencms replication error

Tags: module, copy, cluster-computing, replication, opencms

I'm using opencms8 and i have set up a clustering server system with ocee-replication module to replicate the resources.
I always use this function without problem, but after the last replication, the function not work anymore. It give me an error message who says:

---

Error while filling the list "Replication Resources".
Reason: Comparison method violates its general contract!

---

This error stuck my replication process. When i click the server who i want replicate, it give me that error and don't show me the append publish resources that i want replicate.
I don't kwon why it appear all of a sudden. I haven't change any of my configuration file.

Someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself for that people who encounter my same problem.

I solved the problem by publish some files (maybe that one who give me that kind of error).
I don't know how but it work, maybe when i publish the resource, i rewrite their UUID, so avoid the comparision problem.

Anyway, i hope it can be usefull for the other
Greeting
Marco